# Intersection of two series

Tags: sequences-and-series, discrete-mathematics, diophantine-equations

I'm looking for the solutions to
$$\begin{eqnarray}
z &=& x_0 + i \Delta_x \\
z &=& y_0 + j \Delta_y \\
i &\ge& 0\\
j &\ge& 0
\end{eqnarray}$$

Well, I know that

- there is a solution only if $y_0 - x_0$ is a multiple of $GCD(\Delta_x, \Delta_y)$.
- the formula for $z$ is $z = z_0 + k \Delta_z$ with $\Delta_z = LCM(\Delta_x, \Delta_y)$ and $k\ge 0$;

But I'm unable to compute a general formula fo $z_0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd be better off looking for an *algorithm* than an algebraic "formula".

First, suppose without loss of generality that $y_0>x_0$. Also, for simplicitly, we can assume that $x_0=0$ (otherwise, subtract $x_0$ from both $x_0$ and $y_0$ and add it to $z_0$ at the end).

Now if $gcd(\Delta_x,\Delta_y)>1$, divide everything by the gcd and multiply it in afterwards. Then we can assume that $\Delta_x$ and $\Delta_y$ are coprime.

What we're looking for is then the least $j\ge 0$ such that $$y_0+j\Delta_y \equiv 0 \pmod{\Delta_x} $$

But that must be the principal representative of the solution to $j_0\equiv -y_0\frac{1}{\Delta_y} \pmod{\Delta_x}$. You can compute the reciprocal of $\Delta_y$ modulo $\Delta_x$ using the extended Euclidean algorithm, and then reduce its product with $-y_0$ modulo $\Delta_x$ afterwards.

Finally compute $z_0 = y_0+j_0\Delta_y$, and then apply the corrections for the "without loss of generality" above.